# Deploy React Application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, deployment, cors

I want to make my application in production so I created a build folder and when I follow the steps in [React deployment documentation](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment)  I'm facing the problem

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://www.website.fr/api/login' from
>   origin 'http://localhost:5000' has been blocked by CORS policy:
>   Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource.

When I am in dev it works fine and the API works fine. For the information, the link for my API's I made them in package.json like

```
"proxy": "http://www.website.fr"
```

Answer (score 1):

That's not a deployment problem - when you deploy your app (I'm assuming at `http://www.website.fr`), the user won't get CORS error, because it won't be a cross-origin request.

It's a development problem, and for the development process' use it can be solved by disabling CORS check in your browser (there's command line parameters for Chrome, and there's CORS Everywhere plugin for Firefox, among other solutions). Or you can ask the backend guys to (temporarily) enable CORS, if that's a viable solution.

Answer (score 0):

i think you should install cors lib for your backend app